# How to implement ACL using Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, acl

Im currently validating 3 times. Example delete link is only allowed to super upers. So Im validating 3 times.

1-In the constructor (Redirect)
2-In the wicket link contruction (Set Link to False)
In the Onclick (Return)

I feel like an idiot validating 3 times. It should be something I can use to implement security in my wicket application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable components depending on the role a certain user has. For this you have to

- implement your own authorization strategy and
- annotate your component according which role is allowed which action.

A sample for this approach can be [found here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/authorization/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Wicket-Auth-Roles.
You need to implement your own AuthenticatedWebSession and add annotations to your components.
The following tutorial contains links to examples and how to integrate it:

https://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wicket-security